# How to add custom javascript file to footer emberjs

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I want to add my custom js file to the footer of my ember app. I added my js file to the vendor folder but the file is rendered in the begining of my template.

Comment: try adding entry in ember-cli-build.js file for bundling custom js files..by the way not understood your question !

Comment: Yes i did but the js file is compiled into the vendor.js. I want to add my vendor.js file to the foot.

Comment: You *could* just edit the `index.html` and move the `<script>` tag to the bottom if thats what you want. But remember that you must load the `vendor.js` before the `your-app.js` because it also contains ember. You could also don't `app.import()` the file and use an additional <script> tag if its in your build output. Its there if its in the `public` folder, or use `funnel` and `merge-trees` to manually add it.